# How I can use function set in JInput of Joomla

Tags: input, joomla

```
$input = $this->input;
$input->set('aaa',1);
```

but when I print`_r($this->input)` have `'aaa'=>1`.

I assign it in `$input` not `$this->input`.

I don't want that. I want 'aaa' set in $input, not set in $this->input

sorry for my bad english >"<

Comment: explain more what you want?

Comment: I want 'aaa' set in $input, not set in $this->input

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, objects are not copied on assignment, only their reference. In your example, `$this->input` and `$input` both point to the very same object.

If you want a copy of an object, you must `clone` it. See [Object Cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) in the PHP manual.

`<?php
$input = clone $this->input;`